# How to get transactional emails to display proper logo and email address for multi store magento 1.5.1

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.5, transactional-email

When I set up email transaction templates in Magento 1.5.1, it is not pulling the correct information into the template.

I have gone through and created and saved templates though the transactional email setup for each store.  Each store has its own theme and should be pulling the logo and email in for that specific theme.  However, when I send an email or preview it, it does not pull the correct logo, contact info, or email for that store.  It is just bringing up the global information.

Are there specific variables that I must change to get this to work.  Here is the code that is being used for the New Account template.

```
<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                <!-- [ header starts here] -->
                <table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}" alt="{{var store.getFrontendName()}}"  style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a></td>
                    </tr>
                <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Dear {{htmlescape var=$customer.name}},</h1>
                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 16px 0;">Welcome to {{var store.getFrontendName()}}. To log in when visiting our site just click <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">Login</a> or <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">My Account</a> at the top of every page, and then enter your e-mail address and password.</p>
                        <p style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0; padding:13px 18px; background:#f9f9f9;">
                            Use the following values when prompted to log in:<br/>
                            <strong>E-mail</strong>: {{var customer.email}}<br/>
                            <strong>Password</strong>: {{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}<p>
                        <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 8px 0;">When you log in to your account, you will be able to do the following:</p>
                        <ul style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 16px 0; padding:0;">
                            <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; Proceed through checkout faster when making a purchase</li>
                            <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; Check the status of orders</li>
                            <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; View past orders</li>
                            <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; Make changes to your account information</li>
                            <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; Change your password</li>
                            <li style="list-style:none inside; padding:0 0 0 10px;">&ndash; Store alternative addresses (for shipping to multiple family members and friends!)</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">If you have any questions about your account or any other matter, please feel free to contact us at <a href="mailto:{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}</a> or by phone at {{config path='general/store_information/phone'}}.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you again, <strong>{{var store.getFrontendName()}}</strong></p></center></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Magento 1.4.1 now. And there **already** all needed variables pulled from different store configurations based on which store some event was created. Yes, you need to change all specific settings in Admin > System > Configuration (emails, names), but *don't forget to change the scope* (in dropdown menu on a top left side of a page) of a settings being changed.

There is must be no hardcoded values in templates, all specific settings must be variables.